# Javascript - Find first index in a matrix based on condition

Tags: javascript, search, indexof

Having the following matrix array:

```
[
[0,0,1,1,0,3],
[1,0,0,1,2,5],
[0,0,1,2,4,9]
]
```

I would like to find index 3 which is the first column where all values are larger than 0 (1,1,2).

What would be an efficient technic to search for this index?

Comment: Please review the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Where are you stuck? What has your research turned up? What does your attempt to solve the problem look like? What specific issue have you had with it? Right now, this reads like "please do this for me," which is not what SO is about.

Comment: It is working for you, @Shlomi ?

Comment: Yes thanks, works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `every` method in combination with `findIndex` method.

The `findIndex()` method returns the `index` of the **first** element in the array that satisfies the provided **callback** testing function.

The `every()` method tests whether all elements from an `array` passed the test `provided` by the **callback** function.

```js
let matrix=[[0,0,1,1,0,3],[1,0,0,1,2,5],[0,0,1,2,4,9]]
let index = matrix[0].findIndex(function(cell,i){
   return matrix.every(function(row){
    return row[i] > 0; //or return row[i];
   });
});
console.log(index);
```

### Or simply using `arrow` functions.

```js
let matrix=[[0,0,1,1,0,3],[1,0,0,1,2,5],[0,0,1,2,4,9]]
let index = matrix[0].findIndex((cell,i) => matrix.every(row => row[i] > 0));
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
[0,0,1,1,0,3],
[1,0,0,1,2,5],
[0,0,1,2,4,9]
]

var res = arr.map((a) => a.filter((b) => b > 0))
or
var res = arr[0].filter((b) => b > 0)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map all truthy values and fincd the index with `Boolean` as callback.

```js
var array = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3], [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5], [0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 9]],
    index = array
        .reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => b[i] && c))
        .findIndex(Boolean);

console.log(index);
```